# how to run AsyncTask every min?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to run AsyncTask every 1 minute, by using handler,but it doesn't work:(
In AsyncTask I am reading data from Sqlite DB and drawing result in mapview, aim of doing like that is another service updating my Sqlite every 1 min by taking real data from server and i want keep mapview updated too.
Is there any possible way of calling AsyncTask every minute rather than using Handler?

```
public Runnable getData; 
        private final Handler _handler = new Handler();
        private static int DATA_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000;
  getData = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    getDataFrame();
                }

                private void getDataFrame() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     _handler.postDelayed(MapViewActivity.this.getData, DATA_INTERVAL);
                     new DrawFromDataTask();

                }
            };

DrawFromDataTask is described below:
private class DrawFromDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, FriendItemizedOverlay> {

            @Override
            protected FriendItemizedOverlay doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mDbAdapter.open();
                List<Refresher> nearFriends = mDbAdapter.getAllRecords();

                for(Refresher friend : nearFriends)
                {
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(friend.Latitude);
                    double lon = Double.parseDouble(friend.Longitude);
                    OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1000000),
                                                                    (int)(lon* 1000000)),
                                                                    "" + friend.name,
                                                                    "" + friend.type);


                    mFriendOverlay.addOverlay(item);
                }

                return mFriendOverlay;
            }

             protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                 setProgress(progress[0]);
             }

             protected void onPostExecute(FriendItemizedOverlay result) {
                 System.out.println("in AsyncTask execution!");
                 Location loc = get_location();
                    final double mLatitude = loc.getLatitude();
                    final double mLongitude = loc.getLongitude();

                    // get the last location from the database
                    GeoPoint lastLocation = new GeoPoint(
                                     (int) (mLatitude * 1E6),
                                     (int) (mLongitude * 1E6));
                    Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow);     
                    int amountOFplayers = result.size()-1;
                    for (int j=0; j<amountOFplayers; j++) {

                        result.getItem(amountOFplayers).setMarker(marker);  

                    }
                    //System.out.println("Number of overlays -- "+amountOFplayers);

                    mMapView.postInvalidate();
                    //mMapView.invalidate();
                    // animate to last location
                    mMapController.animateTo(lastLocation);
                    // zoom to the required level
                    mMapController.setZoom(ZOOM_LEVEL);

             }


         }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work". Add some debug logging and see what is happening. Are you ever posting the `getData` Runnable? Does it run only once? Does it write any errors to the logcat?

Comment: There is no errors, it runs only once.

Comment: The AsyncTask runs only once? or the getData Runnable runs only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the broadcast intent that runs on minute tick and then just execute the Async task. It is more accurate.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK

Make sure you create `new` instance every time, since the thread object cannot be reused/relaunched unless you create new instance.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `Timer`, `TimerTask` and run in a fixed rate `scheduleAtFixedRate()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a service to poll the server every one minute, why dont you use Google Cloud Messaging for android(previously C2DM).. In that way you can send some notification to your app that yes data is changed on the server, which then leads you to change some data in your db if needed ,and then start the thread.
But yes I sincerely dont have any idea about your actual requirements